The DragGesture is moving together with the NSWindow's movable property
I have customized a slider view and used DragGesture to detect sliding events. However, triggering this sliding event also causes the NSWindow containing the view to move along with it.
struct MusicPlaySlider: View {
    @Environment(\.currentWindow) private var currentWindow
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    @State var lastCoordinateValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var sliderRange: ClosedRange<Double> = 1...100
    var thumbColor: Color = .white
    var minTrackColor: Color = .white
    var maxTrackColor: Color = .black.opacity(0.4)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gr in
            let thumbHeight = gr.size.height * 1.1
            let thumbWidth = gr.size.width * 0.03
            let radius = gr.size.height * 0.15
            let minValue = gr.size.width * 0.015
            let maxValue = (gr.size.width * 0.98) - thumbWidth
            
            let scaleFactor = (maxValue - minValue) / (sliderRange.upperBound - sliderRange.lowerBound)
            let lower = sliderRange.lowerBound
            let sliderVal = (self.value - lower) * scaleFactor + minValue
            
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(maxTrackColor)
                    .frame(width: gr.size.width, height: gr.size.height * 0.95)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius))
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(minTrackColor)
                    .frame(width: sliderVal, height: gr.size.height * 0.95)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: radius))
                HStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1)
                        .foregroundColor(thumbColor)
                        .frame(width: thumbWidth, height: thumbHeight)
                        .offset(x: sliderVal)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged { v in
                        self.currentWindow?.isMovable = false
                        if (abs(v.translation.width) < 0.1) {
                            self.lastCoordinateValue = sliderVal
                        }
                        if v.translation.width > 0 {
                            let nextCoordinateValue = min(maxValue, self.lastCoordinateValue + v.translation.width)
                            self.value = ((nextCoordinateValue - minValue) / scaleFactor)  + lower
                        } else {
                            let nextCoordinateValue = max(minValue, self.lastCoordinateValue + v.translation.width)
                            self.value = ((nextCoordinateValue - minValue) / scaleFactor) + lower
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded({ _ in
                        self.currentWindow?.isMovable = true
                    })
            )
        }
    }
}


How can I prevent the NSWindow from moving when the DragGesture is triggered?

I cannot reproduce on macOS 15.1.1.

I'm using macOS 14.6.1
